# Domain Address GX XEvo2 .NET

Tags: c#, .net, genexus

Quería consultar si alguien ha utilizado el Domain Address con GX XEvo2 para web generando .NET. Podrían pasarme un ejemplo? Estoy creando la variable del tipo Address(varchar(1024)), la agrego al webpanel y al ejecutarlo se muestra simplemente como char, qué me puede estar faltando?
Gracias! Saludos!!

Comment: Deberías agregar código de lo que estás intentando, eso facilita a los usuarios el ayudarte.

Comment: Es que el dominio address es en realidad un char, en edición se comportará como un string normal... La diferencia está en que mostrandola como readonly gx lo hace en forma de link que te lleva a Google maps para que resuelva la ubicación geografica del string que pusiste.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu comentario!! Hice eso mismo que explicás pero poniendo la variable en pantalla como Geolocation, y anduvo re bien!! Saludos